# SQL Replication Returns No Status

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

We are synchronizing SQL Server CE with SQL Server 2008 R2.

There are two different publications we need to synchronize, and we call them each in sequence.

This is a (greatly abbreviated) sample of what we are doing.

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeReplication repPub1;
repPub1.Synchronize();

System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeReplication repPub2;
repPub2.Synchronize();
```

99% of the time, the first publication runs, then the second.

However, 1% of the time, the first publication finishes, according to the replication monitor, but not as far as C# is concerned, so we sit and wait indefinitely on the `repPub1.Synchronize();` step, and the second publication never starts. The only thing we can do is have the user terminate and start over when they get tired of waiting.

Has anyone seen this before? Anyone know how to make this more fail safe?

Suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: First questions I usually ask are: What CU level on the server and web server (must be in sync) and what SQL CE build. Desktop or Windows Mobile?

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 CU7 for the server and SQL CE 3.5 (latest version that supports merge replication)  The mobile database is running on Windows Mobile.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that.  SQL CE is 3.5.5386

Comment: Then I suggest you upgrade the replication components on both client and server to the latest version: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/08/sql-server-compact-35-sp2-downloadable.html

Comment: We upgraded to CE 3.5 SP2 and everything seems to be working properly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to CE 3.5 SP2 on both the SQL Server and in our mobile application and that seemed to fix the problem.